# Remove a column with positive values?

Tags: r

I have data:

```
structure(c(1.44, 0.28, 1.7, 0.4, 0.03, -0.61, 0.33, 
-0.84), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("19", 
 "10", "20", "1"), c("A", "B")))
```

Remove the column with values are all positive. Here A should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `colSums` :

```
df[, colSums(df < 0) > 0, drop = FALSE]

#      B
#19  0.03
#10 -0.61
#20  0.33
#1  -0.84
```

Or using `apply` :

```
df[, apply(df < 0, 2, any), drop = FALSE]
```

If you convert data into dataframe, you can also use :

```
Filter(function(x) any(x < 0),  as.data.frame(df))
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
as.data.frame(df) %>% select_if(~any(. < 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using apply: Considering **df** as the dataframe in which your columns are present, the below command should work

df [ , apply(df, 2, function(x) length(which( x < 0 ))) > 0]

A small explanation of the above function

- First argument of the apply function is the dataset (**df**) on which you need to apply a logic
- The second argument takes **1** (or) **2** where **1** corresponds to perform operations at a **row** level and **2** corresponds to perform operations at a **column** level *(here what you needed was column level operations)*
- The third argument takes the function needed to perform, in case of in-built functions (lets say ***sum***) then **function(x)** as in the above code is not needed

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(df) %>% 
     select_if(~ sum(. < 0) > 0)
```